# RED SCREEN in titanium

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, titanium

I have created an ipad app using Titanium Appcelerator created UNSIGNED IPA using of the same and delivered the same to the client. Client gave UNSIGNED IPA given by me to one of its customer who has implemented Xen Mobile (MDM). Now customer has started facing following error.[image: Error displayed while opening application]

I have created IPA using development certificate & provisioning profile provided by client and submitted the same to client but that doesn't show any kind of error.
This screen shot clearly indicate that this screen would not be displayed in case of distribution. I really don't understand why this screen is being displayed. Can any one please help me out.

Comment: have you created IPA with titanium or Xcode ?

Comment: I have created IPA with Xcode 6.1. Actually what I did is that first of all run entire code using Titanium 3.5.1 which would create build folder and this build folder would contain code that could be opened in Xcode. And now after opening that particular code I created IPA.

Answer (score 1):

open up your Xcode project from build folder. Now search for the file `main.m` in your Xcode folder structure on the left panel. Change `NSString * const TI_APPLICATION_DEPLOYTYPE = @"development";` deploy type from `development` to `production` and generate the build form Xcode itself. This will solve your problem.

Comment: Swanand thanks a lot. Would check out the same and let you know whether it works or not.